# Check which thread has locked a QMutex

Tags: multithreading, qt, deadlock, qmutex

I am facing a weird deadlock when doing something in our database program. The critical point is when thread tries to lock a `QMutex`:

```
QMutexLocker locker(&tableMutex_);
```

That makes the program go stuck.

I'm baffled, because no other thread - AFAIK - has access to this mutex. What I want to do now is to figure out which thread has locked it. How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe same thread locked the mutex twice. Try to use recursive version of QMutex (pass `QMutex::Recursive` to QMutex constructor)

Answer (score -1):

Interrupt your hanging program in a debugger and examine the stack traces of all threads.

Comment: I did that, that's how I found where is it stuck. But it could've been locked anywhere on thousands of lines of code.

Comment: @TomášZato: If you are only locking your mutexes with `QMutexLocker` or a similar RAII mechanism, it shouldn't be too hard to check if any of the other threads is in a scope where a QMutexLocker is present.